# Python KeyError problem when loading the saved model in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, nlp, keyerror, transformer-model

I am new to deep learning. I am using a transformer model for bengali language stemming process. Now, I trainied the model and test it with some data and it worked fine. So i saved the model. But when i delete the runtime and create a new runtime and load the previously trained model i get a KeyError. I don't know why I'm seeing this. I hope you guys can help.

Here is the notebook (when i run the model within same runtime) : [Google colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TaLOluMViu8jVqCN5F0UbJyP8rZjlhE5?usp=sharing)

Here you can find the dataset : [Dataset](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-HjpNum2GpgnBe-qGeqfkXjyBHitXJy2/view?usp=sharing)

Here is what happens when i try to load a trained model : [colab link](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q8moMBJpFrMa6EJAegSqYPn7k2wvSj90#scrollTo=AQ423XQWAgc6)

Trained model link : [model link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18pqiBHU3MCVZIIxe9jUE4wZ4sA-mdxVe/view?usp=sharing)

I think the problem is when I am loading a trained model a 'PAD' token is being added with the given word. But it doesn't happen if i train the model and use it in the same runtime. It only happens when i change the runtime and load a saved model. I've tried to fix it but i can't really find the solution. I hope you guys can find it.

I'll be of great help for me if someone can help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please share your code in the question?

Comment: @Quinten I have linked the notebook, in the question please click on "Google colab Notebook" for the code that works when i use the model in the same runtime. And click on "colab link" for the error while trying to load and run the model. Did you find the code ??

Comment: @DAShaikh sorry for disturbing you but you've already solved a issure related to this model. Can you help me with this one? this will be a greate help

Comment: @MahirRAfid could you include the related code in your post. Your question should have the necessary information to answer it. Additionally, people may not be able to access whatever link you're giving. and/or don't want to go through your entire code. StackOverflow is not a service to fix your code for free, please provide a minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example with details about the errors you have, and what you tried to fix it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Asking for recommendations might not be appropriate on the Stackoverflow (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but it might be possible to ask the question on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com. Also, logging it on https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp/beta/discussions/76949597